# make preparation for or make provision for？

Tags: word-choice

> The local authorities realized the need to make [ ] for elderly people in their housing programmes.

A. preparation

B. provision

I found that "preparation" and "provision" have a shared meaning: get ready for something. Is there any subtle distinction that I need to know?

Comment: _Preparation_ is getting ready for something, _provision_ is providing something. Local authorities need to provide suitable housing for elderly people.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I got a quotation from a dictionary which indicates that provision has this meaning: preparations that you make for sth that might or will happen in the future. I suppose that this implication is similar to getting ready for something. According to the dictionary, providing something is just one of provision's meanings, and the phrase "make provision for" exists only if it suggests the meaning that I mentioned at the beginning of the comment.

Comment: The sentence talks about the local authority _providing_  housing for the elderly, not _preparing_ it (getting it ready for someone to live in). Yes, _provision_ can mean 'making plans for something to be available in the future', but this is about people who are elderly _now_.